# Extend SELECT IF statement

Tags: mysql

I am using a SELECT IF statement to translate data from my database:

```
IF(status = 1, 'Status one', 'Status two')
```

If the status is 1 the statement shows `Status one`. If the status is something else the statement shows `Status two`.

I want to extend this statement and show:

```
IF status = 1, 'Status one'
IF status = 2, 'Status two'
IF status = 3, 'Status three'
IF status = 4, 'Status four'
```

Does someone know how I can do that?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
    (CASE 
        WHEN status = 1 THEN 'Status one'
        WHEN status = 2 THEN 'Status two'
        WHEN status = 3 THEN 'Status three'
        WHEN status = 4 THEN 'Status four'
        ELSE 'Incorrect Option'
    END) AS statustext
FROM yourtable;
```

As per ysth's comment, this is more compact and probably more efficient:

```
SELECT
    (CASE status
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Status one'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Status two'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Status three'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Status four'
        ELSE 'Incorrect Option'
    END) AS statustext
FROM yourtable;
```

Thanks ysth!

Comment: When you are comparing the same expression, you can say instead `case status when 1 then 'one' when 2 then 'two' when 3 then 'three' when 4 then 'four' else 'nope' end`

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT('Status ',
        CASE WHEN status = 1 THEN 'one'
             WHEN status = 2 THEN 'two'
             WHEN status = 3 THEN 'three'
             WHEN status = 4 THEN 'four' END) AS label
FROM yourTable
```

## Demo